# Berlin Apart-hotels 16 Year old

Tags: germany, covid-19, hotels, minors, berlin

I'm 16 years old. I'm going to be doing an internship in Berlin for nearly 3 months.
It's extremely likely that I'm going to be needing an apart-hotel, accommodation at a Youth Hotel or something like that for the first few days of my stay before I find a room to hire or similar. I will be travelling unaccompanied.

- **Are there apart-hotels that allow minors to rent their rooms?**
- **Do the rules regarding COVID19 look like they will be loosened so as to avoid quarantine by the 14th of June?**

Regarding the forum's rules on questions that attract non-objective answers, I will try to accept the answer which offers the best legal advice and is the most useful for someone in a similar situation to mine.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Where are you arriving from? The quarantine rules depend on it, so that part of your question can’t really be answered without that information.

Comment: @ChrisH From Spain

Comment: Not an answer, as I do not know, but have you been in contact with the place you are an intern and asked them to help you? Likely by finding you a place to stay in a rental room or in the home of someone working for them temporarily. (Hotels are very expensive for most young people, Youth Hostels are more the price range for most.)

Comment: @Willeke I'm sorry I should have included Youth Hostels in my question. yes I've contacted them and they've told me they are working on it but I need a backup plan.

Comment: as a minor, If you're doing an internship , your employer should help you settle somewhere safe and legal.

Comment: Good luck finding a room for only 3 months in Berlin. Be prepared to spend all the time at the Hostel. You need to announce your arrival via online form, where you also may enter negative test results in order to shorten quarantine, unless you're coming form a high-risk or variant-area. As of today, midday, Berlin is allowing private stays in hotels, beginning on the 11th of June - though your stay will probably fall under "business trip".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.